# React - Dragging a file drags text/plain instead

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm working on an Image Uploader that allows the user to drag and drop images. It works some of the time, but once in a few it just decides not to work. I checked the `e.dataTransfer` of the drag and drop events, and when it doesn't work, the `types` array is either empty or has `text/plain` instead of `Files`, and the `files` is empty.

I assumed this might be because of where I grab the file when I start dragging it, but there doesn't seem to be a difference - sometimes it works and sometimes it just doesn't. Also, seems to me like there has to be some way to ensure that it works...

Tried screwing around with the `dataTransfer.effectAllowed` and `dataTransfer.dropEffect` to no avail...

Here is my Drag Event handler

(`onDragEnter`, `onDragOver`, `onDragLeave`)

```js
const handleDrag = (e: React.DragEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // some stuff to set styling of the component
}
```

And my drop handler:

```js
const handleDrop = (e: React.DragEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // more styling stuff

  // temporary warning I have displayed so I can see when it doesn't work more easily
  if (!e.dataTransfer.types.includes("Files") setError();

  // handles the displaying of the image
  if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files[0]) onFileDrop(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
}
```

I checked, and when it doesn't work, the path to the image - like `file:///home/USERNAME/Pictures/fantastic_mr_fox_2.jpg`... I tried to simply display the image at that path but got an error message that reads `Not allowed to load local resource`.

Is there any way to either prevent the path from being the dragged item or to use that path and display the image?

Would highly appreciate help!